# Hibernate: mapping parent to child entity with 2 references to one column in child?

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, cascade

I am trying to have a `cascade delete` within my entities. But I think that it is being stopped by the fact that I have **2** references to the one column in my child `entity`.

In my child Dog entity I originally had the following field:

```
 @Column(name = "KENNEL_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String kennelId;
```

I then added this because I wanted to get a list of all child entities related to the parent:

```
 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "KENNEL_ID" )
    private Kennel kennel;
```

In my parent Kennel entity I also added this to refer to the field in the child I added:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "kennel",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Dog> dogList= new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

Before I added the 2nd child reference and the parent references, cascade delete worked for all of my entities. However since I have added them it does not.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a problem of mapping parent and child to the same class.The problem is that you need to maintain both ends of the bi-directional-relationship by hand.

```
child.setParent(parent)
parent.addChild(child)
```

BTW: Setting it only on one side (the one which is responsible to store the relationship in the database), store and reload the entity will work in some cases too. (And you will find this dirty trick in many old tutorials). But in my opinion it is bad practice. (In your test case, it would require to clean the cache before you reload the parent after the child is saved.)

```
public void setDogList(List<Dog> dogList) {
        this.dogList.clear();
        this.dogList.addAll(dogList);
    }
```